# How to change table which I want shape?

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

This is my query

```sql
SELECT
  a.value,
  a.code,
  a.kndnr
FROM
  raw a
  JOIN z_raw b ON a.code = b.zgrpc
WHERE
  b.gubun = '09811'
  AND concat(a.gjahr, a.poper) = '2024001'
  AND a.artnr = 'F004000'
  AND a.prctr = '021011'
  AND a.artnr_t = 'H50M'
  AND (a.kndnr = '10027' and a.kndnr = '10026')
```

This is the result

| value | code | kndnr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300000 | A00 | 10027 |
| 305000 | A00 | 10026 |
| 300332 | A01 | 10027 |
| 305442 | A01 | 10026 |

How can I make that using a SQL query? Normally my SQL environment is Databricks SQL, but it is fine to me to teach Oracle or MySQL SQL,
I will make fit.

I always try to use pivot, but I failed, so please teach me suitable ways. It is not suitable to use pivot. I expect this result

| A00 | A01 | kndnr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300000 | 300332 | 10027 |
| 305000 | 305442 | 10026 |

Comment: Do you have only A00 and A01 codes?

Comment: MySQL != Oracle. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Feelfree  no i have more but i want to describe easy way

Comment: @MT0 it just describe that actually i prefer mysql

Comment: this is an area where the answer will be drastically different for different RDBMS

Comment: re tried to use/not suitable for pivot, what you are asking is how to do a pivot query.  show what you tried?  mysql does not have an explicit pivot keyword, but does have ways to do it (conditional aggregation, plus dynamic sql if you can't do a fixed set of columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use conditional aggregation. Here is the example

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.code = 'A00' THEN a.value END) AS A00,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.code = 'A01' THEN a.value END) AS A01,
    MAX(a.kndnr) AS kndnr
FROM
    raw a
    JOIN z_raw b ON a.code = b.zgrpc
WHERE
    b.gubun = '09811'
    AND CONCAT(a.gjahr, a.poper) = '2024001'
    AND a.artnr = 'F004000'
    AND a.prctr = '021011'
    AND a.artnr_t = 'H50M'
    AND (a.kndnr = '0000')
GROUP BY
    a.kndnr;
```